# Better way to add element at the beginning of F# sequence

Tags: f#, sequence

F# `List` provides the `cons` (`::`) operator to add an item at the front of a list. Is there a function to do the same for the `Seq`? The only way I came across is using `Seq.append` as follows. Is there a more efficient/elegant way of doing this?

```
> let myLst = [1..5]
> 0::myLst;;
val it : int list = [0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5]


> let mySeq = {1..5}
> Seq.append (seq [0]) mySeq;;
val it : seq<int> = seq [0; 1; 2; 3; ...]
```

Possible duplicate, but not really answering my question.

[[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153890/f-add-an-element-to-a-sequence) uses `Seq.append` as above

Comment: Note that you can just use `Seq.append [0] mySeq`, you don't have to wrap `[0]` in a call to `seq`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It may help to recall that F# sequence is a calculation, indeed. No matter how you are going to achieve it, in the end of the day you should have a new calculation that, if being enumerated, first yields the appended element, and then yields the old sequence. In most direct form this can be achieved using [a sequence expression](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597449):

```
> let mySeq = {1..5}
> seq { yield 0; yield! mySeq };;
val it : seq<int> = seq [0; 1; 2; 3; ...]
```

`Seq.append` library function is just an optimized implementation of semantically the same action.

Comment: Gene Belitski: thanks. so are you basically suggesting to use `Seq.append` since it is optimised?

Comment: @vis: I do not think a universal "one-fits-all" recommendation makes sense. The answer, as usual, would be "it depends...".
Nevertheless, when you know the underlying principles you can make choices yourself.